# Apache Pulsar - Authorization failed on topic - Don't have permission to administrate resources on this tenant

Tags: java, apache-pulsar

I'm getting this exception:

```
org.apache.pulsar.client.api.PulsarClientException$AuthorizationException: Authorization failed example_ingest_producer on topic persistent://myTenant/myNamespace/myTopicName with error Don't have permission to administrate resources on this tenant
```

when trying to connect to Pulsar from our client application. I'm running Pulsar 2.4.2.

I confirmed that I'm connecting to the correct endpoint (`pulsar+ssl://pulsar-ms-tls.mydomain.com:6651`), and we're using SSL+TLS.

What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is occurring because you're not using the correct token to connect, or the role associated with your token lacks sufficient permission. You will need to ensure that you are using the correct token (and that it has the right permissions) to enable you to connect.